# unity2d transform and position of instantiated UI object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

according to [the document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)(quoted bellow for convenience)

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
```

if I instantiate a prefab and pass a transform as the second parameter then the newly instantiated gameobject will be the child of the specific gameobject of the passed transform, right? And yet I presume that the position of the newly instantiated gameobject should be adjusted according to parent.

I made an UI-Image as a prefab: with the posX, posY configured and anchored as following:

[image]

And in the hierarchy:

[image]

And the instantiate C# script snippet:

```
GameObject pageIcon = transform.parent.FindChild("PageIcon").gameObject;
Instantiate(unSelectDot, pageIcon.transform);
```

And the result is that the newly instantiated object have a weird PosX and PosY:
[image]
Why does that happen? who changed the PosX and PosY? Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does that happen? who changed the PosX and PosY? Did I
>   misunderstand something?

The solution to this problem depends on your Unity version.

Before *Unity 5.5*, when you do `Instantiate(unSelectDot, pageIcon.transform);`, the GameOject will be instantiated in **world space** instead of the position of the prefab.

From *Unity 5.5* and above, when you do `Instantiate(unSelectDot, pageIcon.transform);`, the GameOject will use the Object position as the local position by default.

It is very likely that you are using Unity version under `Unity 5.5`. In this case, pass `false` to the third parameter of the `Instantiate` function.

```
Instantiate(unSelectDot, pageIcon.transform, false);
```

If this does not work, try `true`. Although, `false` should do it.

*Note from Unity 5.5 [release Note](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.5.0)*:

> Core: Using Object.Instantiate(Object, Transform) will now use the
>   Object position as the local position by default. This is a change
>   from the 5.4 behaviour, which used the Object position as world.

Comment: Hi, @Programmer, sorry for the delay of response, not available to the net during weekend, things turn out that, When I use `Instantiate(unSelectDot, pageIcon.transform, false);` the prefab will be instantiated as expected, also note that I'm using Unity 5.5.2f1, and the release note found hard to understand, may be the **Object** stands for the *Object* who does the Instantiation ? cheers! anyway, thanks!

Comment: *"may be the Object stands for the Object who does the Instantiation ?"* I don't think so. The Object param is the prefab. Although, the documents are sometimes wrong but that is rare. As long as passing `fasle` to the parameter fixes the problem, you shouldn't worry about this any more

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I want to Instantiate an object relative to its parent is like:

```
Instantiate(unSelectDot, GameObject.Find("PageIcon").transform);
```

Try this, I hope it will work for you